# Print output of Quantile function horizontally in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I am running this code to generate quantiles in python 3, however it prints the output vertically. Is it possible to print the output horizontally

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

r = np.random.random_sample((5,))
pd.Series(r).quantile(q = np.linspace(0,1,11))

0.0    0.112624
0.1    0.261145
0.2    0.409665
0.3    0.531582
0.4    0.626897
0.5    0.722211
0.6    0.746804
0.7    0.771397
0.8    0.818495
0.9    0.888097
1.0    0.957699
dtype: float64
```

I want the output to be like this

```
0.0         0.1         0.2         ...
0.112624    0.261145    0.409665    ...
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert it into DataFrame and use transpose `df.T`:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

r = np.random.random_sample((5,))
df = pd.DataFrame(r).quantile(q = np.linspace(0,1,11))

print(df.T)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

r = np.random.random_sample((5,))
data=pd.Series(r).quantile(q = np.linspace(0,1,11))
print(*data.index,'\n', *data)
```